# Should Protractor can also be used for database testing directly?

Tags: database, protractor

As protractor is primarily for end-to-end testing, so to cover user like high level scenarios on the UI level,

> should we use it to test database directly as well?

by establishing db connectivity and firing queries to verify the database states may be before & after the user actions in the UI ?

or

for plain direct db testing to check stored procedures to test business rules/functionality?

which one is the correct one, and what is the right way to use it with protractor?

Answer (score 3):

There is no right or wrong answer to this question.

In general, *UI end-to-end tests should follow/mimic the user scenarios* - in a high-level sense, making UI actions and checking the results of these actions in a browser. The way a database is changed is usually checked inside the functional tests of your backend/API, not inside the UI e2e tests.

On the other hand, there will always be more things to test, more things to check - if one is a perfectionist, it is really hard to stop in covering a specific application under test with tests and stopping making all kind of assertions after every set of actions. You always have ways to go deeper into checking the results of your tests.

Also, the other point is, if you would connect to a database inside your test and check how a test affected the data, you have one more thing to keep track of - your database queries would have to be up to date with your database schema.

To conclude, it really depends on the importance of a specific application or functionality under test. If it is, say, something related to payments or money transactions, or launching rockets etc, then the deeper you go with it - the better.

Comment: Thanks Alecxe for the answer .If somebody chooses to go deeper for whatever the reason, could you please suggest the good general implementation approach?

Comment: @VishalAggarwal I've personally used `sequelize` ORM for it, but I remember tackling with supporting the database schema and making the tests more complicated. It's always about how worthy and critical is what you are testing.

Comment: I'd generally agree, but I would put it slightly differently. Protractor is meant to end2end test your UI. If you connect to a database, it should only be to verify that your UI is properly interacting with the database. It should not be used to verify your database itself (that should be assumed to be tested in other ways). Using a DB within protractor this way does complicate things, but I have used this technique in the past. It all depends on the kind of app that you have.